# Token or Password asked each tiem I open jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter

Each time I open jupyter notebook, after few minutes it asked for password or token
I found it difficult to search.
if anyone of you know how to do this please reply
It happens with anconda and also when I now newly installed python in my window laptop same happens

I tried on line but could not get answer that can work